# Is there are way to use ghost classes in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I always encounter problems when trying to use 'legacy' `JavaScript` code from within `TypeScript 2.0` code.

This is in spite of knowing that you need a type definition file `(*.d.ts)` for doing that and reading the 'best pratice' articles [Writing Definition Files](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) and [Best Practices](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html).

My current problem is that I want to use `TypeScript` in a `React/Alt` application. The `TypeScript` compiler is configured to directly emit es5 code for the browser (i.e. "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json).

The problematic part is converting a Action js file to ts.

I followed the [Alt recommendations to doing that](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/blob/master/docs/typescript.md). The example there is the following:

```
/**AltJS is a "ghost module" full of non-instantiable interfaces and typedefs to help you write easier code
 * included in our alt.d.ts type definitions
 */

class AbstractActions implements AltJS.ActionsClass {
 constructor( alt:AltJS.Alt){}
 actions:any;
 dispatch: ( ...payload:Array<any>) => void;
 generateActions:( ...actions:Array<string>) => void;
}

//This class will now compile!!
class SomeCoolActions extends AbstractActions {
 constructor() {
     this.generateActions(
         "firstAction",
         "secondAction",
         "thirdAction",
         "fourthAction
     );
 }
}
```

The problem with this example is that it will compile *but it will not work*. When trying I always get the following error message in the browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: AbstractActions is not defined(…)

The reason for that is obvious as well: `AbstractActions` is an (abstract) **Ghost class**, i.e. it is only there to make the typescript compiler happy. In the Alt module there is no such thing called `AbstractActions`. All the magic that makes `generateActions` work is from the `Alt.createActions` factory:

```
let someCoolActions = alt.createActions<Actions>(SomeCoolActions);
```

Hence here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to repair this, i.e. use an `AbstractActions` ghost class for making TypeScript happy but have a 'dummy' implementation to keep the browser happy as well?
2. More general: Is there a way to ensure that the (legacy) JS implementation of a module I define a type definition (*.d.ts) for, is present when the browser executes the JS app?

Comment: why not make AbstractActions an interface? that will only be present at compile time but not at runtime.